# Print all words in a String without split() function

Tags: string, python-3.x, printing, words

I want to print out all words in a string, line by line **without** using split() funcion in Python 3.

The phrase is a str(input) by the user, and it has to print all the words in the string, no matter it's size.Here's my code:

```
my_string = str(input("Phrase: "))
tam = len(my_string)



s = my_string
ch = " "
cont = 0
for i, letter in enumerate(s):
    if letter == ch:
        #print(i)
        print(my_string[cont:i])
        cont+=i+1
```

The output to this is:

Phrase: Hello there my friend

```
Hello
there
```

It is printing only two words in the string, and I need it to print all the words , line by line.

Comment: Is your code printing any blank lines?  If so, why might that be?  Hint: look closely at the value of `cont` and how it changes.

Comment: No, I meant after the first two words.

Comment: It prints the two words and nothing more, not even blank lines

Comment: That's not what I get.  Are you running exactly the code above?  Are you sure `s` and `my_string` are the same (you don't need both names for the same string; using only one will make the code clearer).

Comment: You should also take a look at what happens if there is only one word in the input (just "Hello", for example).

Comment: Now I found the blank line, I wasn't looking correctly. I don't know why it is printing the blank line.

Comment: The answer is in my previous comments.

Comment: I tried changing the value of the variable cont , but still no way to print more than two words

Comment: Honestly, you were closer to a good solution than the accepted answer. Basically, you need an `else` clause for your `for` statement, and you don't want `cont += i + 1` you want `cont = i + 1`. Like this: http://pastebin.com/aXGdtpy2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def break_words(x):
    x = x + " " #the extra space after x is nessesary for more than two word strings
    strng = ""
    for i in x: #iterate through the string
        if i != " ": #if char is not a space
            strng = strng+i #assign it to another string
        else:
            print(strng) #print that new string
            strng = "" #reset new string
break_words("hell o world")

output:
   hell
   o
   world
```

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, if this isn't a homework question, but I will leave you to figure out the why.

```
a = "Hello there my friend"
b = "".join([[i, "\n"][i == " "] for i in a])
print(b)
Hello
there
my
friend
```

Some variants you can add to the process which you can't get easily with if-else syntax:

```
print(b.Title())  # b.lower() or b.upper()
Hello
There
My
Friend
```

Comment: Were you purposefully trying to obfuscate? `[i if i != " " else "\n"  for i in a]` is much more straightforward.

Comment: yes... and no... the variant I gave demonstrated a different approach to the conventional if else syntax, which, if it was a homework assignment, would have been the expected answer.  This probably accounts for the reason my originally accepted answer is no more :)

Comment: Apparently, the `(x,y)[bool]` motif was standard before the "ternery" (really, conditional expression) . Before my time :). It seems reasonable enough to me, especially when you want to be succinct, but I think it is hard to read inside a list comprehension.

Comment: first course in CS, 1969... I still love the evolution of languages and the rediscovery of old things.

Comment: My first line of code was in a CS class in the fall 2014, although I was a late bloomer to CS, taking a post-bac course at the local community college at age of 25 to fulfill the requirements to apply to a master's program. Although, I suppose I did have some exposure to BASIC in elementary school, and I would fiddle with small programs on my Ti-83 calculator in middle school / high school.

Comment: 'ternary operator' to me is a new-ish term to me... much like how '#' evolved from 'number key' to 'pound key' to 'hashtag'.  Definitely an evolutionary field, unlike some other disciplines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124046/discussion-between-nan-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).